# vector iterators incompatible C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, multimap

Okay, looked for it over the web and inside stackoverflow for about an hour and did not find anything like this, sure there are several cases, but none of them seems to have the same root.

Okay, I need to iterate over a `multimap` and they are stored in a `vector`. Here goes the code:

```
DataVector::iterator curr = m_rawBuffer[0]->begin();
DataVector::iterator last = m_rawBuffer[0]->end();
for( ; curr != last; ++curr) {
    delete (*curr);
}
delete m_rawBuffer[0];

DataVector::iterator curr2 = m_rawBuffer[1]->begin();
DataVector::iterator last2 = m_rawBuffer[1]->end();
for( ; curr2 != last2; ++curr2) {
    delete (*curr2);
}
delete m_rawBuffer[1];
```

`DataVector` is a `std::multimap<MyData*>`.

`m_rawBuffer` is a `std::vector<DataVector*>`.

The strangest thing is that the first iterator on `m_rawBuffer[0]` works fine, but iterating over `m_rawBuffer[1]` does not work! And to get even more strange it breaks only in one machine, it runs over distributed system and all other machines are fine.

The `operator[]` from `std::vector` returns a reference, right?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: my suspicion: could it be `m_rawBuffer[0].end()` ?

Comment: @Niall: The error is that when I get to for( ; curr2 != last2; ++curr2) it gives the "vector iterators incompatible" error.

Comment: @Alex: no, the first part of the code works fine. Or are you saying something else?

Comment: Did you recompile it for sure? Did you link it for sure? What compiler?

Comment: Does rawbuffer have item [1] for sure ?

Comment: @PiotrS.:Recompiled it twice and no success. Using MSVS2010. I know that it is the new executable because I can attach it correctly to debug.

Comment: @PiotrS.:Yup, it does. Both of the multimaps are instantiated in a previous method and the debug information says so.

Comment: @AugustoCésarMartinsGil, Is it VS2010 or VS2010 SP1? I think there was some issue with iterators that SP1 fixed. IIRC there was a post/answer on this earlier today or yesterday. Else the error doesn't make sense to me. `begin` and `end` return the same type.

Comment: Do `m_rawBuffer[0]` and `m_rawBuffer[1]` have distinct values? It is hard to say with only the currently shown code, but deleting `m_rawBuffer[0]` will leave a pointer to a destroyed object in `m_rawBuffer`.

Comment: Can other threads have access to rawBuffer at that time?

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan: Here is the constructor:
BufferManager::BufferManager()
 : m_isReading(false),
 m_write(0),
 m_read(!m_write),
 m_rawCdrBuffer()
{
 m_rawCdrBuffer.push_back(new CdrDataVector());
 m_rawCdrBuffer.push_back(new CdrDataVector());
}

So they do have distinct values.

Comment: @PiotrS.: Nope. Only one thread to clean it up.

Comment: Are you running into this bug? https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/545013

Comment: @Niall: I will be installing SP1 soon, after that I will give you more feedback.
About the bug link, it seems that vector.end() that is doing that.

Comment: Compiled in Release now and it worked fine. Trying to update to SP1, I thought that my machine was already with SP1... new job...

Comment: Installed SP1 and still no success on debug. It is really strange. On my machine works perfectly, but on another machine it gets stuck.

Comment: Does `~MyData` remove itself from its container ? Are `m_rawBuffer[0]` and `m_rawBuffer[1]` equal ?

Comment: @Jarod42: The destructor of MyData only sees MyData itself, nothing else. They are both differents.